# How upload file in NestJS with websocket and FileInterceptor?

Tags: websocket, nestjs

In docs https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload we can use FileInterceptor, but how use it in EventsGateway?

For example:

```
@SubscribeMessage('user:setAvatar')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('userAvatar', {
    storage: diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, 'uploads/');
        },
        filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
        }
    })
}))
async setAvatar(client: any, @UploadedFile() file: any): Promise<void> {
    console.log(file);
}
```